Output results to a windows form- textbox or lable
I am trying to get my network adapter results to output to a textbox or label in a windows form. The output is perfect when shown in the console, but when it outputs to the form all I get is a bunch Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
below is the powershell code I am using
  $NIC_Status=Get-NetAdapter  * | Format-List -Property "Name", "Status"
$TxtBoxOutput.Text=$NIC_Status

Tried different output format. I am expecting the output to show the same as in the console

Use $NIC_Status | Out-String to preserve the formatting but also to convert those formatting objects to a single string. However, the better approach would be to use a DataGridView instead.
